# Magento EE 1.14.4.4 Upgrade - Console error in Checkout Page. "decorateTable is not defined"

Tags: console

We have upgraded our Magento EE to  1.14.4.4.

After upgrade, the Cart page and Checkout Page review step throws below-console error in IE.

> decorateTable is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue and fix finally. Below are the details

We have faced some console errors and button click issues in our site after upgrading to 1.14.4.4. These errors break place order functionality, toolbar options and compare links in the PLP page.

**Console Errors:**

> 'review' is not defined
>
> 'decorateTable' is not defined
>
> 'setLocation' is not defined

In this 1.14.4.4 release, Magento fixed the button issue (button click not changing the state as expected) in **Admin->System->Compilation->Tools->Compiler** section. For this, they have added a new JS function called **buttonDisabler()** in

> js/varien/js.js

```
function buttonDisabler() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.save');
  buttons.forEach(button => button.disabled = true);
}
```

This function caused the issues in IE 11 Browser. The "<" operator which is used in this function is not supported in IE, which throws a syntax error and stops the next functions.

To Fix this, we have updated the function as below (replacing the "<" operator") in

> js/varien.js.js

```
function buttonDisabler() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.save');
    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.disabled = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don’t forget to accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you @pong. Done

Comment: Great job. Thank you! @Agnes